# Android layout loaded twice

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

On button click event I'm using setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); it works correctly.

When if I try to start new activity with Intent and startactivity commands it loads layout twice it looks like layout loading correctly then 1 second same layout loaded again.

Before start activity its loaded single time.

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {           
        String selected = spinner0.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(selected.equals("Item 2"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(second_layout.this,MainActivity.class);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you changing your old activities layout before you start your new activity?

Comment: Why are you setting the layout again in `onClick` listener?

Comment: sorry guys I didn't mention this layout my second layout not my mainactivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this line is the problem.-

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

`setContentView` will just change the layout for the current activity, so you're changing the current layout to `activity_main`, and then you open the `Intent` for `MainActivity` class.

Just remove that line.

Comment: You don't need to, starting `MainActivity` will change the layout for you. You should have an `onCreate` method in `MainActivity`, which calls `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: I guess I understand ok. I'm trying now. Okay it works like you said thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting a new activity, there is no need of setContentView while starting the intent.

The intent which is getting started will have the code for loading the layout. So please remove this line.

I hope, in your MainActivity.class, you will already be writing setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) and this is enough for showing the required layout. So remove this extra line which you have included while starting the intent.

Comment: Yeah I get it, using setcontentview and starting new activity cause loading twice yes I remove that line it works thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set your second activity layout in your first activity before starting your second activity. It will set automatically in your second activity's `onCreate()` method. So you should write `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` in your `MainActivity's` `onCreate()` method. Just remove it from the onClick listener.

So write in your `onClick` as below:

```
show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {           
        String selected = spinner0.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(selected.equals("Item 2"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(second_layout.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

And in your `MainActivity` you have to set your layout as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }
}
```

Comment: That code I write above its my second layout not my mainactivity, I forget it to write initially.